# Multiple animation keyframes in the same frame issue

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes, graph-editor

Never have seen such an issue before. But recently after the animation baking or copy-pasting KEYFRAMES, I get multiple keyframes in one frame (see X rotation f-curve). Did I mistakenly toggle some random setting that prevents nearby keyframes from merging? Or is it a bug?
[image]